# Symfony2 authentication via 3rd Party REST API

Tags: php, api, symfony, restful-authentication

I'm writing an application using Symfony2 which will interface with the [Wordnik REST API](http://developer.wordnik.com/docs).

Currently, the Wordnik API does not offer OAuth capabilities, so I have to accept a username and password which I'll then transparently pass to the API interface.

I'd like to integrate this API authentication into Symfony2's security system, but so far I haven't been able to identify what the best implementation route is.

I don't think the [custom user provider](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html) is correct, because the password is not stored in my system. All examples regarding [custom authentication providers](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) seem to pertain to the securing of a part of an application *as* an API, rather than *against* a REST API.

It's not clear to me to what extent the FOSUserBundle helps to solve this problem either.

*The ideal flow:*

- User provides credentials.
- Credentials are passed to the 3rd party REST API
- If the credentials are correct:

  - A corresponding "third party user" Entity is created by my application, if it doesn't exist.
  - The user is authenticated using this "third party user" Entity.

What is the best way to implement this within a Symfony2 security context?

Thanks!

*Related Questions:*

- [Problems configuring user authentication by external API on Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264066/problems-configuring-user-authentication-by-external-api-on-symfony2)

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem. Could you please share your code for how you implemented this?

Comment: @Steffan - It's going on 2 years since this code was written, but you can see the provider / token that we wrote here: https://github.com/freen/wordrot/tree/584a7b361ba21eb1cf5303949cb6b3d30eecf687/src/WordRot/PlayBundle/Security/Authentication  .... on subsequent commits I removed the PHP backend in favor of trying out a Node backend instead, so that commit is the last state of the PHP.

Comment: Thx alot, but I found an easier way to do it with the [guard system](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/guard/login-form) thx to @DevDonkey from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376315/symfony2-authenticate-is-not-executed?noredirect=1#comment56501487_34376315) post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to implement a custom authentication provider as described in:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

I can't tell you what the best way is but just to help you get started:
You create a listener, a token, a provider and a factory.

The attemptAuthentication method of the listener takes the credentials provided by the user and creates a new Token with that input. At the end of the method you'll add a:
return $this->authenticationManager->authenticate($token);

Your provider will use this token in the authenticate method to send the API request.

For non-existing users you have two options:
- create a user in the authenticate method after the API call and after you check whether it already exists which I believe is NOT they way to go
- create your own authentication failure handler which is like https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.php but at the top of the onAuthenticationFailure method you add 
if ($exception instanceof UsernameNotFoundException && (null !== $token = $exception->getToken()) && $token instanceof YourWordnikToken) {
 // create that user here
}

That's just the basic idea how it works...I'm on IRC with the nickname hacfi - let me know if you need further guidance

Comment: hey hacfi, I don't see you in the channel at the moment :) you can find my app's code here: https://github.com/freen/wordrot ... I'm currently getting this error:

 `Fatal error: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent in /[...]/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php on line 43`

... It seems like the configuration is slightly off, if it is still trying to use the UserAuthenticationProvider (should be using WordnikProvider) -- Do you see any issues with my implementation?

Comment: I'll clone the repo to tonight and try to fix it!

Comment: Hey Hacfi, thanks for your help! I merged in your pull request, [solved a constructor argument error on the authentication provider](https://github.com/freen/wordrot/commit/0ec3ae9f33bc66fbcdcad668b47de0ee2120d9fe), but I'm still getting the exact same error as before.

Comment: See pullrequest...next points:
- work on the token
- add api call to authenticate in the WordnikProvider

Comment: The main problem seems to be its continued loading of the DaoAuthenticationProvider. Still looking into it. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Why is that a problem? Setup xdebug and see for yourself that at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.1.7/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall.php#L64 it checks Dao first and then yours. Dao is kind of ignored.

Comment: I don't think that's correct - the application seems to load Dao which in turn loads (extends) the UserAuthenticationProvider. [See the full stacktrace.](https://gist.github.com/freen/5006382) However WordnikProvider does not extend that provider, but [directly implements the AuthenticationProviderInterface](https://github.com/freen/wordrot/blob/master/src/WordRot/PlayBundle/Security/Authentication/Provider/WordnikProvider.php). That's why I believe the error is in the configuration of the implementation, and the WordnikProvider is never loaded.

Comment: If you're still interested in looking into this issue, I opened a new question here: [Symfony2 won't load custom authentication provider, loads DaoAuthenticationProvider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008721/symfony2-wont-load-custom-authentication-provider-loads-daoauthenticationprovi).