# Symfony2 won't load custom authentication provider, loads DaoAuthenticationProvider

Tags: php, rest, authentication, symfony, restful-authentication

*This is a continuation of [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928514/symfony2-authentication-via-3rd-party-rest-api).*

Hi,

I'm implementing, in a Symfony2 application, a custom authentication provider in order to authenticate against the Wordnik REST API.

On application load, no matter what request path, this is the exception I get:

`( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent in /[..]/WordRot/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php on line 43`

You can see the full stacktrace [here](https://gist.github.com/freen/5006382).

Second to last line in the trace reveals that **it is loading the** `DaoAuthenticationProvider`:

`18 0.0217  1922792 Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider->__construct( )   ../appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:3071`

But none of my configuration refers to that provider, or anything that extends it. My custom provider directly implements the `AuthenticationProviderInterface`.

So I assume that my configuration is wrong, and somewhere I need to be explicitly setting the `WordnikProvider`, but I'm not sure where! Research has not provided any clues to this issue.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Files**

- [/app/config/config.yml](https://github.com/freen/wordrot/blob/master/app/config/config.yml)
- [/app/config/security.yml](https://github.com/freen/wordrot/blob/master/app/config/security.yml)
- [/src/WordRot/PlayBundle/Security/Authentication/Provider/WordnikProvider.php](https://github.com/freen/wordrot/blob/master/src/WordRot/PlayBundle/Security/Authentication/Provider/WordnikProvider.php)
- [/src/WordRot/PlayBundle/Security/Authentication/Token/WordnikUserToken.php](https://github.com/freen/wordrot/blob/master/src/WordRot/PlayBundle/Security/Authentication/Token/WordnikUserToken.php)
- [/src/WordRot/PlayBundle/Security/Firewall/WordnikListener.php](https://github.com/freen/wordrot/blob/master/src/WordRot/PlayBundle/Security/Firewall/WordnikListener.php)
- [/src/WordRot/PlayBundle/DependencyInjection/Security/Factory/WordnikFactory.php](https://github.com/freen/wordrot/blob/master/src/WordRot/PlayBundle/DependencyInjection/Security/Factory/WordnikFactory.php)

Comment: FYI: His vendor folder was corrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line return $this->authenticationManager->authenticate(new WordnikUserToken($username, $password, $this->providerKey)); in the WordnikListener goes to
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationProviderManager (classes.php)
authenticate.
$this->providers are DaoAuthentificationProvider, WordnikProvider and AnonymousAuthentificationProvider.
From the DaoAuthentificationProvider it only uses the method supports($token):
return $token instanceof UsernamePasswordToken && $this->providerKey === $token->getProviderKey();

which returns false so next in line is WordnikProvider.

Oh..misread: the error is in the constructor:
parent::__construct($userChecker, $providerKey, $hideUserNotFoundExceptions); seems to fail. Running PHP 5.4.10 or so I DON'T have an error!!

Either rm -rf vendor and run composer install again or try using a different PHP version!!

Comment: Removing the vendors and re-installing them bypassed this error and revealed two very bizarre "class not found" errors in `bootstrap.php.cache` (depending on whether I ran `update` or `install`). As recommended, I upgraded my composer.phar, re-installed all vendors (on a fresh clone of the repo) and there were no more problems loading the WordnikProvider! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A had to create something like this a week ago.
At the and, I created a custom user provider, where I simply call the api and with the response i create the user or not.

I would advise to read this:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply András. I've read about creating a custom UserProvider, but what I'm trying to implement right now is a custom AuthenticationProvider. Ideally I'd separate the logic, and handle authentication for the API within the AuthenticationProvider.