# Symfony2 authenticate is not executed

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I did follow the [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) to implement a custom authentication provider, but authenticate() will not execute from the WsseProvider.

I checked the supports() function and it works as it should.

PHP Storm gives the following error with the authenticate function:

> Declaration must be compatible with AuthenticationManagerInterface->authenticate(token : \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\TokenInterface)

But I have allready imported TokenInterface as explained in the cookbook:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
```

So PHP Storm asks me to change to:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\TokenInterface;
```

But by using this supports() doesnt execute.

Anyone know why I get this error, and/or why authenticate doesnt execute?
I followed the steps exactly as it is explained in the cookbook.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\AuthenticationProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\NonceExpiredException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface; //Using this authenticate doesnt work
//use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\TokenInterface; //Using this supports doesnt work
use AppBundle\Security\Authentication\Token\WsseUserToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\StringUtils;

class WsseProvider implements  AuthenticationProviderInterface
{
    private $userProvider;
    private $cacheDir;

    public function __construct(UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $cacheDir)
    {
        $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
        $this->cacheDir     = $cacheDir;
    }

    public function supports(TokenInterface $token)
    {
        return $token instanceof WsseUserToken;
    }

    public function authenticate(TokenInterface $token)
    {
        die('authenticate is executed'); //This doesnt fire

        $user = $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername());

        if ($user && $this->validateDigest($token->digest, $token->nonce, $token->created, $user->getPassword())) {
            $authenticatedToken = new WsseUserToken($user->getRoles());
            $authenticatedToken->setUser($user);

            return $authenticatedToken;
        }

        throw new AuthenticationException('The WSSE authentication failed.');
    }

    /**
     * This function is specific to Wsse authentication and is only used to help this example
     *
     * For more information specific to the logic here, see
     * https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/3134#issuecomment-27699129
     */
    protected function validateDigest($digest, $nonce, $created, $secret)
    {
        // Check created time is not in the future
        if (strtotime($created) > time()) {
            return false;
        }

        // Expire timestamp after 5 minutes
        if (time() - strtotime($created) > 300) {
            return false;
        }

        // Validate that the nonce is *not* used in the last 5 minutes
        // if it has, this could be a replay attack
        if (file_exists($this->cacheDir.'/'.$nonce) && file_get_contents($this->cacheDir.'/'.$nonce) + 300 > time()) {
            throw new NonceExpiredException('Previously used nonce detected');
        }
        // If cache directory does not exist we create it
        if (!is_dir($this->cacheDir)) {
            mkdir($this->cacheDir, 0777, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($this->cacheDir.'/'.$nonce, time());

        // Validate Secret
        $expected = base64_encode(sha1(base64_decode($nonce).$created.$secret, true));

        return StringUtils::equals($expected, $digest);
    }

}
```

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using?  Authentication/TokenInterface makes no sense at all.  Can't see where phpstorm is finding it.

Comment: if youre on 2.8 (which ideally you should be), then [guard](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-guard-authentication-component) is great and makes life much easier.

Comment: Thx @DevDonkey exactly what I was looking for!