# Symfony 3 authenticate user against remote API

Tags: rest, api, symfony, authentication

I've got an application where back-end and front-end are served from different hosts and are two different applications (both Symfony 3 based).

One of them (back-end ofc) handles business logic and keeps users and their roles in it's DB. Back-end provides REST API to be used by front-end. I have no possibility to modify back-end code as it's not my project - I just want to create a front-end for it.

Currently, I'm trying to create front-end app in Symfony 3 but I'm not sure how to make the front-end app authenticate against a remote API and keep no user data (or as little as possible) on its side.

After passing credentials to the backend via REST API a token is sent to front-end application and following API requests (e.g. data the front-end app would present to the user are to be sent with token received after successful authentication).

**My question again: How can I authenticate against remote custom (non-OAuth) API from Symfony 3?**

And additionally: **How to handle token properly later?** (it has to be used while making every request after successful authentication). What is the easiest way to achieve this?

---

I've been struggling to find decent info (maybe a tutorial?) I'm a noob in Symfony :(

Most articles describe providing an API which allows clients to connect to it, not making a client app in Symfony.

What I found:
[Symfony2 authentication via 3rd Party REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928514/symfony2-authentication-via-3rd-party-rest-api) - most relevant, though it describes a flow for Symfony 2 and the accepted answer describes what should be done only briefly

https://blog.vandenbrand.org/2012/06/19/symfony2-authentication-provider-authenticate-against-webservice/ - concerning Symfony 2

http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html - probably the most on topic, however, I don't understand where will app keep it's users (is writing a custom user provider necessary in this example?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already found the answer on your question. That's [custom authentication provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html). You can keep the tokens in your frontend app storage, and just authenticate them. On login, you should create the token via request to backend app, save it in your token storage and that's all. Then you only need to authenticate the token (just see an example of auth provider).

Regarding keeping user data in your frontend app, it's up to you. You don't have to keep any data, therefore if you'd like to show some details (i.e. user name and so on) you have to store that details too (or retrieve it each request - but that will impact the performance). At least you can use caching for that.

So the possible approach is:

1. On login(with login form or elsewhere), just authenticate user in login handler (create your own auth provider as described [there](https://blog.vandenbrand.org/2012/06/19/symfony2-authentication-provider-authenticate-against-webservice/) - don't worry about Symfony 2, security component is almost the same - there are some incompatibilities, but the direction is correct). After successful authentication, store token in your frontend storage (also you can store some user details you need like name and so on).
2. On each request, authenticate the user using the token that's kept in your frontend app storage (that's another auth provider) - you don't need to send request to your backend app.