# Symfony authenticate user against remote API

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, token, symfony-guard

I have an issue, more or less the same as this guy: [Symfony 3 authenticate user against remote API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213994/symfony-3-authenticate-user-against-remote-api)

But my problem is, what do I do with the token?

I used guard, I made an api service where I can retrieve the token, but where can I store it? I wanted to set a cookie but I can't write the cookie from my service, or I won't be able to start the session, so in the answer I don't understand the: "store token in your frontend storage".

There is really no way for me to store the token in a cookie?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so clear what he meant, but i think the best solution is storing it in the session variable.

Answer (score 2):

Why shouldn't it be possible not to use sessions from services? Inject the session component into your service and you're good to go.

```
class TheService {
  public function __construct(SessionInterface $session) {
    $this->session = $session;
  }

  public function stuff() {
    $this->session->set('my_token', 'h3ll0');
  }
}
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

In case you're on a current version of Symfony its autowiring feature will take care of injecting the `session` service, otherwise you'd need to configure the service in your `services.yml`:

```
services:
  my_service:
    class: AppBundle\Service\TheService
    public: true
    arguments: ['@session']
```

Comment: Actually I can use the session, I don't know why I was not thinking about that, I said I couldn't store in a cookie, but the session was a much better choice anyway. Thx! :)