# login to a remote API with a Symfony front

Tags: php, api, symfony, authentication

I've searched a lot, but couldn't find anything very clear on the subject.

I will build a symfony front end, and to login (and get data), we'll connect to a remote api. So I need to have a login form on my symfony app, and when I press login, that will check the api, which will send me back a token if it's correct, and then I'll need that token for every call to the api.

I've read the symfony doc about custom authentication and apiKey authentication, but it's always if it's a backend app.

That guy had the same problem: [Problems configuring user authentication by external API on Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264066/problems-configuring-user-authentication-by-external-api-on-symfony2)
But the answer is basically just the doc.

Basically, I don't understand where I can create a login form that will check the api to get a token, when I have the token I can save it in a cookie and do https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/api_key_authentication.html
(where I would check the cookie instead of the query parameter)

Thank you!

Arvi

Comment: Did you read this? https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html

Comment: It's still mostly how to treat for a backend. Here the app will be purely frontend, no backend at all, but thx :)

Comment: What do you mean with "backend"? Every symfony application is backend with HTML/CSS/JS being the frontend. If it is an API or an actual Website doesn't really matter for the Guard Authenticator.

Answer (score 0):

First you should know which technology is doing the remote API.

For OAuth I would recommend you two bundles:

- FOSUserBundle to keep the users id in your app and some data you may need https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html
- HWIOAuthBundle https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle to connect to a third party API for login/registering Oauth/Oauth2

Comment: It's not OAuth or I would have used HWIOAuth yes, it's JWT.
(And I don't want to persist users locally)